# Cannot navigate to newly installed Sitecore instance

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

I have installed sql server 2008, mongodb and I tried installing a sitecore instance, but for some reason I can't navigate to any pages on the site.  I checked my sql database and iis and it looks like the installation went through without any errors, but I just cant seem to navigate to the site.  Any suggestions?

EDIT:

After the installation it asks to launch the instance, which I do.  When I navigate to YOURSITE/sitecore the page doesn't load and just says "The Page cannot be displayed" standard IE error message when the site cannot be resolved.

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean under "Cannot navigate". What do you see when open in browser http://YOURSITE/sitecore/ ?

Comment: How did you install the site? Using the exe or SIM? Did you add the bindings in IIS and add the entry to the windows hosts file? You need to provide more info, you have given very little info in your question.

Comment: @Anton it just says "The page cannot be displayed" as a standard IE browser or in chrome it says "The Site cannot be reached"

Comment: @jammykam I used the exe to install and after you install it, it gives you an option to launch the instance, which I check the box and click finish, and the browser pops up but I get a "The page cannot be displayed" error as if the site didn't exist.  I did not do any custom bindings in IIS or anything to windows hosts file?  Was I supposed to?  I am following the standard development courses on learning.sitecore.net and there was no mention of doing any of that.  Thanks!!

Comment: Make sure that you have your site in hosts file. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file) However I wonder why it could be absent there. As installer and SIM should modify it.

Comment: @Anton, I went to C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc and opened my hosts file in notepad and its completely blank, maybe that is the problem, what should I put if my site is supposed to be http://testinstance/sitecore?  Thanks again for your help!

Comment: 127.0.0.1 testinstance

Comment: @Anton omg you are a life saver.  Thanks dude!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure that you have your site in [hosts file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)). However I wonder why it could be absent there. As installer and SIM should modify it.

E.g.: for site "testinstance"  you should have next record:

```
127.0.0.1 testinstance
```

Comment: Thanks! yes exactly how did the SIM OR the installer not modify my host files?  I was going through the tutorials on learning.sitecore.net and it mentioned nothing about this.  Thanks for pointing this out again.